# Conditional form rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, conditional-formatting

So I am trying to render a form to start a new darts game conditionally depending on the game type selected. The form has a local state and "knows" which game is selected. So when selecting game "X01" I need a variant, inCondition and outCondition Dropdown whereas the game "Cricket" just needs one additional dropdown for variant (other values than x01 variants). I started to design a game form which looks like this:

*gameform.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SelectInputMultiple from '../common/SelectInputMultiple';
import SelectInput from '../common/SelectInput';
import { games, x01Variants, conditions, cricketVariants } from './assets';

export default class GameForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.players = props;
    this.handleMultipleChange = this.handleMultipleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    selectedPlayers: [],
    game: 'x01',
    x01variant: '501',
    inCondition: 'straight',
    outCondition: 'double',
    cricketVariant: 'cutthroat',
    errors: {}
  };

  formIsValid() {
    const _errors = {};
    if (this.state.selectedPlayers.length === 0)
      _errors.selectedPlayers = 'You need to select at least one player';

    this.setState({
      errors: _errors
    });

    return Object.keys(_errors).length === 0;
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleMultipleChange = e => {
    let _selectedPlayers = [...e.target.options]
      .filter(o => o.selected)
      .map(o => o.value);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedPlayers: { ...prevState.selectedPlayers, _selectedPlayers }
    }));
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.formIsValid()) return;
    let _game = {
      selectedPlayers: this.state.selectedPlayers,
      game: this.state.game,
      x01Variant: this.state.x01variant,
      inCondition: this.state.inCondition,
      outCondition: this.state.outCondition,
      cricketVariant: this.state.cricketVariant
    };
    this.props.onSubmit(_game);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <SelectInputMultiple
          id="players"
          label="Players"
          name="players"
          onChange={this.handleMultipleChange}
          options={this.props.players}
          error={this.state.errors.selectedPlayers}
        />
        <SelectInput
          id="game"
          label="Game Type"
          name="game"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={games}
          value={this.state.game}
          error={this.state.errors.game}
        />
        <SelectInput
          id="x01Variant"
          label="X01 Variants"
          name="x01Variant"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={x01Variants}
          value={this.state.x01variant}
          error={this.state.errors.x01Variants}
        />
        <SelectInput
          id="inCondition"
          label="In Condition"
          name="inCondition"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={conditions}
          value={this.state.inCondition}
          error={this.state.errors.condition}
        />
        <SelectInput
          id="outCondition"
          label="Out Condition"
          name="outCondition"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={conditions}
          value={this.state.outCondition}
          error={this.state.errors.condition}
        />
        <SelectInput
          id="cricketVariant"
          label="Variant"
          name="cricketVariant"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={cricketVariants}
          value={this.state.cricketVariant}
          error={this.state.errors.cricketVariant}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Start Game" className="btn btn-primary" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

GameForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  players: PropTypes.array
};
```

So my goal is to just show the corresponding fields linked to the game type. How can I do that depending on `this.state.game`?

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: Which is your select box component that you want to show on based of this.state.game ?

Comment: x01 will have three select boxes (x01variant, inCondition, outCondition) whereas cricket will just have one (variant) and split-score (upcoming) will have one and Around the clock (upcoming will have one)

Comment: I suggest exporting the forms to their respective components because with a lot of game modes, your component is bound to get pretty messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just conditionally render the variant select input when the game mode is set to "Cricket"

```js
{this.state.game === 'Cricket' && (
  <SelectInput />
)}
```

The reason you can write it as such is because in JavaScript the && operator basically returns the first value if it is falsy and the second value if the first value is truthy. i.e.
a && b will return 'a' if 'a' is falsy, and it will return 'b' if 'a' is truthy.
So in this case when `this.state.game === 'Cricket'` then the JSX code will be returned hence rendering the form input.

One additional tip!
If you want to render one of two JSX elements based on a condition, you can just use a ternary expression!

```js
{this.state.game === 'Cricket' ? (
  // Renders when game mode is 'Cricket'
  <Cricket />
) : (
  // Renders when game mode is NOT 'Cricket'
  <SomeOtherGame />
)}
```

Comment: But I need to hide the three x01 related inputs as well! And there will be more games with other fields as well.

Comment: Then just conditionally render those too! for the x01 inputs you can say this.state.game === 'X01'

Answer (score 0):

So in this case you need a generic and simple solution, so in your state since you have only limited number of games you can have a state variable as shown below.

```
state = {selectBoxEnabled : {xo1: ['xo1variant', 'inCondition', 'outCondition'], cricket: ['variant'], 'split-score': ['split-score_select']} }
```

So the above selectBoxEnabled field has the same key as in your dropdown field

```
Game Select Box : xo1, cricket, split-score has option values
```

So when the user choose an option you will be getting the key as `xo1` Assume

Now you need to find the fields of **xo1** game

```
const findFields = (currentGameKey) => {
  let selectBoxKeys = selectBoxEnabled[Object.keys(selectBoxEnabled).find(key => key === currentGameKey)]
 this.setState(selectBoxKeys)
}
```

Now you know which are the fields to be shown since you are using same component `SelectInput` , you can do a simple [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and render the fields from the config.

I hope this will give a better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was doing my project and in my project, and I faced such a situation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSGGY.png)
if a user selects one of the there options as an option
if the option is one of the three except they select the form lookalike this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQUQJ.png)

else if they select DDP the form will be changed by adding a new input field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ipj.png)

I handle it using a ternary operator based on the input user selected and it works for me

if it's helpful the code snippet will be here

```
{
  ddp !== undefined ? (
    incotermData == ddp ? (
      <Controls.Input
        name="exchangeRate"
        label="Exchange Rate"
        onChange={(e) => setExchangeRate(e.target.value)}
      />
    ) : (
      <></>
    )
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).